# JavaFX get access to a Tab or TabPane from a TabContent(Node)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there a way to get a reference to `Tab` or `TabPane` without no improvised way if you have reference to only the `Node` inside the `Tab` for eg

```
TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
Tab tab = new Tab();
tab.setText("new tab");
Rectangle drect = new Rectangle(200,200, Color.LIGHTSTEELBLUE);
tab.setContent(drect);
tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab,new Tab("tab 2"));
```

assume i only have reference to `drect` how can i get `tab`. 
I am not interested in `Node.setUserData()` also `drect.getParent().getClass().getName()` returns 
`TabPaneSkin` anon inner class `TabContentRegion`: two strangers.

All i am trying to say is `Node.getParent()` should return the parent `Node` , general uni-knowledge **(** *node's representation in the scene graph can be traced with getParent()* **)**, but, when it comes to `Tab`s its all wrong, hence my question

**EDIT**

Why i needed this, suppose you have `TabPane` consisting of soo many `Tab`, in one particular `Tab` you have a `TreeView`s  as its `Node-Content` which is selected out of some conditions, and for that particular `TreeView` you have different Custom `Cell`s because its `TreeItem`s differ in UI and function- like changing `styles` binding `Fonts`& other bindables and Animating `Tab` hiding other `Tab`s in the `TabPane`, closing other `Tab`s

with this scenario following this approach seems legit for me as, you do not do unnecessary stuff, like exposing children to bad weather. :-)

Thanks Sir James_D

Comment: A `Tab` is not a `Node`, so there's no way `getParent()` could give you the `Tab`. Since there's really no sense in which your node "knows" it's been added to a tab, there's no way to get the tab from the node, unless you engineer one. In the code you posted, you have a reference to the tab, so if you need it later you just need to organize your code to have access to it. Perhaps edit your question to explain in a wider sense what you are trying to do.

Comment: okay so `Tab` is not a `Node`, but its content area takes in a `Node`, a `Node`'s representation in the scene graph can be traced with `getParent()` so how come  tracing is not legit, even `ContextMenu`,`MenuItem` can be traced-they are also not `Node`s- i get what you are saying, but in normal relation, there should be trace. that was what i was gunning for, but it seems, there is nothing like that. i will make up some edit. btw, Thanks for your time Sir @James_D

Comment: If you keep calling `getParent()` recursively, at some point you get to the `TabPane`, no? But really, you should explain why you need this (or think you need this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tab` itself is not a `Node`, so you can't get the tab just by iterating through the scene graph in any way. You can get to the `TabPane` if you go up far enough in the hierarchy. For example:

```
private TabPane findTabPaneForNode(Node node) {
    TabPane tabPane = null ;

    for (Node n = node.getParent(); n != null && tabPane == null; n = n.getParent()) {
        if (n instanceof TabPane) {
            tabPane = (TabPane) n;
        }
    }

    return tabPane ;
}
```

will return the nearest `TabPane` containing the node passed in, or `null` if the node is not in a tab pane.

However, needing this just seems like your design is wrong. If you put a node in a tab pane, at some point you create a tab, so you should just organize your code so you have the reference to the tab available.

Comment: now you talking :), let me try it sir - also if it works you will get a bounty from me. "_However...your design is wrong_"  .No  i am just breaking rules. i guess.  :) brb

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old question, but I will post the solution for someone how is still struggling with this issue.

The following is the FXML structure example of the `TabPane`.

```
<!-- (1) -->
<TabPane>
  <tabs>
    <!-- (2) -->
    <Tab>
      <!-- (3) -->
      <content>
        <!-- (4) -->
        <Pane>
          <!-- (5) -->
          <Node />
        </Pane>
      </content>
    </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

The following method returns the `Tab` object which includes the `Node` specified as an argument.

```
public static Tab getParentTab1(Node node) {
    // <TabPane> object (described as (1) in the FXML example)
    TabPane tabPane = null;

    // <Tab> object (described as (2))
    Tab tab = null;

    // The object of the tab content area
    Node tabContentRegion = null;

    ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class<?> innerClass = null;

    try {
        innerClass = loader.loadClass("com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TabPaneSkin$TabContentRegion");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Node n = node.getParent(); n != null && tabPane == null; n = n.getParent()) {
        // If the node is an instance of the inner class of TabPaneSkin
        if (n.getClass().isAssignableFrom(innerClass)) {
            tabContentRegion = n;
        }

        if (n instanceof TabPane) {
            tabPane = (TabPane) n;
        }
    }

    if (tabPane != null && tabContentRegion != null) {
        // The list of the <Tab> objects
        ObservableList<Tab> tabList = tabPane.getTabs();

        for (Tab t : tabList) {
            // t.getContent() returns the first <Node> object on the <Tab> (most likely it's a <Pane> described as (4))
            // t.getContent().getParent() returns the TabPaneSkin$TabContentRegion object
            System.out.println("content: " + t.getContent());
            System.out.println("parent: " + t.getContent().getParent());

            if (t.getContent().getParent().equals(tabContentRegion)) {
                tab = t;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return tab;
}
```

1. Get the `TabPane` object and the **tab content area** of the `Tab`
   object from `Node` object.
2. Scan all `Tab` objects who are contained in the `TabPane` (that is retrieved in the phase #1).
3. Get the `Tab` object whose content area is equivalent to the **tab content area** (that is retrieved in the phase #1).

The simpler way is shown below.

```
public Tab getParentTab2(Node node) {
    TabPane tabPane = null;
    Tab tab = null;
    Node tabContentRegion = null;

    for (Node n = node.getParent(); n != null && tabPane == null; n = n.getParent()) {
        if (n.getStyleClass().contains("tab-content-area")) {
            tabContentRegion = n;
        }

        if (n instanceof TabPane) {
            tabPane = (TabPane) n;
        }
    }

    if (tabPane != null && tabContentRegion != null) {
        // The list of the <Tab> objects
        ObservableList<Tab> tabList = tabPane.getTabs();

        for (Tab t : tabList) {
            if (t.getContent().getParent().equals(tabContentRegion)) {
                tab = t;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return tab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solutions

To get TabPane:

```
private TabPane getParentTabPane(Node node) {

    if(node==null)
        return null;

    final Parent parent = node.getParent();
    return Optional.of(parent).filter(TabPane.class::isInstance).map(TabPane.class::cast).orElseGet(()->getParentTabPane(parent));
}
```

To get Tab:

```
private Tab getParentTab(Node node) {

    Tab tab = null;
    while(node!=null) {

        final Parent stackPane = node.getParent();
        if(!(stackPane instanceof StackPane)) {
            node = stackPane;
            continue;
        }

        final Parent tabPane = stackPane.getParent();
        if(!(tabPane instanceof TabPane)) {
            node = tabPane;
            continue;
        }

        final Node n = node;
        tab = Optional.ofNullable((TabPane)tabPane).map(TabPane::getTabs).map(List::parallelStream).orElseGet(()->Stream.empty()).filter(t->t.getContent()==n).findAny().orElse(null);
        break;
    }

     return tab;
}
```